# Multithreading Architecture for N Repeating Tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, threadpool, executorservice

I have N tasks, each to be repeated after its own specific delay Interval(N) using a fixed thread pool size that will usually be smaller than N.

Since there will usually be a shortage of threads, preference should be given to executing a different task rather than repeating a recently completed task.

I was thinking of using an outer ThreadPoolExecutor with N nested ScheduledThreadPoolExecutors. I'm not really sure how to go about this in the most optimal way since each of those classes maintains its own internal thread pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the use of a PriorityQueue as answered by assylias, you can also solve this architecturally, by having a simple executing ThreadPoolExecutor, and another ScheduledExecutorService, which will insert the tasks after a given delay.

So every task has the executive Runnable, and an insertion Runnable, and will, after successful execution, tell the ScheduledExecutorService to run the insertion Runnable after a given delay, which will then put the task back into the ThreadPoolExecutor.

As code:

```
// myExecutionTask
void run() {
  doSomeWork();
  scheduledExecutor.schedule(myInsertionRunnable, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

and

```
// myInsertionRunnable
void run () {
  threadPoolExecutor.execute(myExecutionTask);
}
```

Effectively this will automatically cycle the tasks in the ThreadPoolExecutor, as those tasks that have already been finished, will be at the end of the queue.

**Edit:** As discussed in comments, when using the scheduler's `fixedRate` or `fixedDelay` functionality on a very busy system, tasks added later might be executed less often than task that have been added earlier, as the system seems to prefer tasks that are already executing when deciding for the next one to run.

In contrast my solution above cycles these tasks properly, although there can be no guarantee on a busy system, that the requested delay is exact. So they might be executed later, but at least always in FIFO order.

Comment: This achieves what I want in the simplest way. Another benefit is that the interval for repetition starts counting only after the completion of the current task, which is what I want.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it seems that I can simply add all my tasks at once using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit)`. If `initialDelay` is `0`, won't this automatically queue tasks in a way that guarantees that new tasks will always run before repetitions, and repetitions will run in the order in which their delays expire?

Comment: If you use the fixedDelay or fixedRate function, this might work, but for once you cannot change the delay after each execution (if thats even a requirement), and for second: if too many tasks are requested to run, they might pile up eventually (depending on the implementation of the scheduler, not sure how it is done internally), as there might be no execution time left for new tasks. While tasks will pile up to a certain extend with my idea as well, all tasks are at least guaranteed to execute in a semi-regular fashion.

Comment: Just did some tests, and it seems like tasks added later to a very busy system (with both fixed delay and rate) seem to get left behind. They will be executed, but not regularly. First task added was executed 692 times, while the 20th task added was only executed 76 times.

Comment: I'm accepting this even though I'm going with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor since I will use this method if I have problems with overloaded later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) and use timestamps to define priorities - something like:

```
class Task {
    AtomicLong lastRun;
    Runnable r;

    void run() {
        r.run();
        lastRun.set(System.currentMillis);
    }
}
```

Your ScheduledExecutorService (one thread) can then add the task N to a PriorityQueue every Interval(N).

And you can have a separate consumer running in your FixedThreadPool that takes from the Queue (using a reverse comparator so that the tasks run more recently will have a lower priority).

That is a little sketchy but it should work.

Comment: Do delays in a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor block queued tasks from running? With a thread pool size of 1, if I first add a task with a 10 second delay and add a task with a 2 second delay after that, will the second task execute first?

Comment: @Locutus In my proposal, the task run by the STPE is to add a task to the queue, not to run it - so it returns almost instantaneously. Tasks are run by a FixedThreadPoolExecutor, which, when a thread becomes available, takes the next task from the PriorityQueue.

Comment: I asked as I was thinking of a variation and not your implementation exactly.

Comment: @Locutus If your STPE has only one thread and a task is scheduled every 2 seconds but takes 10 seconds to run, it will only run every 10 seconds (the running task will delay the next ones).

Comment: I meant what if two tasks are scheduled with different initial delays on a single threaded STPE and the second one has a shorter delay. Will the second one execute first? STPE has an initial delay as well as a period for subsequent repetitions.

Comment: I want to schedule a task to wait for the interval duration and repeat only after the last execution has completed. This means I can't keep adding it from the scheduled executor at a fixed interval.